# Start Recyclerview from a particular cursor position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which is linked to a CursorLoader.

So my question is how to start from a particular position is database when loading the RecyclerView.

I don't want to use scrollToPosition because i don't want those items be loaded in the view initially.

In other words i want to start the recycler view from the middle of the data set or from a particular row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Used scrollToPositionWithOffset after finishing the loading.